# How does VLC play youtube videos?

Tags: video, download, vlc-media-player, youtube

How does VLC open and play youtube videos?
If you press Ctrl+N and enter the url of a youtube video, it loads for a few seconds and then plays the video.

How does it parse the HTML code?

Comment: How exactly does a positrack rear end on a Plymouth work, it just does,,,"Joe Dirt"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VLC has [integrated](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/share/lua/README.txt) the [Lua scripting language](http://www.lua.org/) to allow users to do things at different times in the playback pipeline.  One of the extension points that VLC exposes via Lua is called a playlist extensions.  With this type of extension, you can take the URL passed to VLC and transform it to a new URL or set of URLs.

VLC ships with some default Lua extensions, one of which is the [`youtube.lua`](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=blob_plain;f=share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua;hb=HEAD) extension.  You can read the code for yourself there, but basically the script takes the video URL and pulls in the HTML and parses it to get the video metadata and a URL it can use to play.

Just as a side note, you can see the compiled Lua scripts that ship with VLC in the `<VLC_INSTALL_DIR>/lua` directory.